# Troubleshoot python daemon that quits unexpectedly?

Tags: python, strace

What's the best way to monitor a python daemon to determine the cause of it quitting unexpectedly? Is strace my best option or is there something Python specific that does the job?

Answer (score 1):

I would generally start by adding logging to it. At a minimum, have whatever is launching it capture stdout/stderr so that any stack traces are saved. Examine your `except` blocks to make sure you're not capturing exceptions silently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pdb`](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html):

`python -m pdb myscript.py`

Running your program like this will cause it to enter post-mortem debugging if it exits abnormally. If you have an idea where the problem is you can also use `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` at the point you want to start debugging. Also logging profusely helps.

Comment: This appears to require human interaction. It runs fine for a period of days so this wont appear to work. Is there a non-interactive debug mode?

Comment: You could try running it in [`screen`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen), then when it triggers the debugger you can attach to it, and debug it interactively. Non-interactive debug mode?? I guess that'd be logging!

Comment: I meant something akin to "bash -x" where is provides "debug" output but doesn't require someone stepping through it or any "keyboard interaction".

Comment: If you want verbose debug info it's only going to be available if you or someone else programs that feature into whatever you are using (by adding extra logging).

Comment: So nothing equivalent to "bash -x" exists for python? That's surprising.

Comment: Python is a programming language. It does what you tell it to do. You can implement a `-x` command line switch to print verbose logging in your program if you choose to.

Comment: Zeekay, I appreciate the help but implementing a version of "bash -x somescript.sh" in python would require modifying python and not your python program.

Answer (score 0):

As the answer above, try to add Logging, however be carefull if you are using python-daemon module it will not work with Logging module when logging to a file, so you should make the logging manually to a file.

Also, make your daemon restarts after it has failed by running it inside a loop and catch exceptions inside the loop.

Example:

```
while True:
    try:
        log_to_file("starting daemon")
        run_daemon()
        log_to_file("daemon stopped unexpectedly")
        sleep(1)
    except Exception as err:
        log_to_file(err)
```